# SQL query showing different answers while executing in SQL Editor and through Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I am using Laravel queries in my project. I am getting different outputs when running corresponding query in SQL query editor in phpmyadmin.

I have this code in Laravel:

```
$oneInvoiceDue=Invoice::where('created_by',$created_by)
                        ->where('date','<=','DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')
                        ->sum('amount_due');
```

And in SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(amount_due) WHERE date <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30) AND created_by = 12345
```

Each one gives different results. Here `created_by` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of the Query Builder's `where` method will be escaped and quoted because it will be considered to be a string value. So in order to explicitly tell the Query Builder to view it as a SQL statement you need to use either `DB::raw()` like so:

```
->where('date','<=', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))
```

Or `whereRaw` to have an entirely raw SQL where statement:

```
->whereRaw('date <= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')
```

You can read more in the Laravel Docs on [Raw Expressions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions) and [Advanced Wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres).

---

Also, for future reference you can use the `toSql()` method to get the query being generated by Laravel's Query Builder so you can see exactly what SQL statements are being executed:

```
$sqlQuery = Invoice::where('created_by',$created_by)
       ->where('date','<=','DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')
       ->toSql();
```